# Array behaving as a variable

Tags: c++, ogre

Have encountered an interesting and frustrating problem with using the Vector3 as an array.

```
Ogre::Vector3* vertices;
...
vertices = new Ogre::Vector3[vertex_data->vertexCount];
...
for (size_t j = 0; j < vertex_data->vertexCount; ++j, vertex += vbuf->getVertexSize())
{
    ...
    vertices[current_offset + j] = (orient * (pt * scale)) + position;
}
...
vbuf->writeData(0, vertex_count, vertices, true);
```

In the final line, and above; the 'vertices' variable is a simple Vector3 (x,y,z) rather than an array of such.

The code compiles fine but obviously there is only 1 triangle rendered. The iterator runs as expected, and j iterates, in this case vertexCount is 72.

Vector3 is defined as:

```
typedef Vector<3, Real> Vector3;
```

Has anyone run into a similar problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `vertex_count`?

Comment: *the 'vertices' variable is a simple Vector3 (x,y,z)* -- Looks like a pointer to me.  `Ogre::Vector3* vertices;`

Comment: *The code compiles fine* -- That doesn't mean anything, really.  A code compiling fine only means there are no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether the program is logically correct.

Comment: What is `current_offset`? If it's greater than zero in your final iteration, you've got a buffer overrun.

Comment: _the 'vertices' variable is a simple Vector3 (x,y,z) rather than an array of such._ - what does that mean? And how did you notice? Please try to create a [mre] and be more precise about expected and actual behavior.